# Find floating-point numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `Balance` with a column `Coins` of double type in my MySql database. However, in fact, I store int values there. So, I want to change the type from double to int. But before, I want to be 100% sure that there are no floating-point numbers in this column.

What kind of SQL request should I write to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
select coins
from balance
where coins <> floor(coins);
```